# How should we tag posts on Meta discussing what should be in the parent site's FAQ?

Tags: support, status-completed, meta-tags

We've got a number of questions here on the Meta discussing what should be in Android.SE's FAQ.  Is there a particular tag that should be used for these discussions?  Should I just make one called "AE-FAQ"?

Technically this is a meta *meta* **meta-tag** question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, on meta.stackoverflow they use <kbd>faq-proposed</kbd>. Seems reasonable to me.

Especially since some people have already started using it: https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq-proposed

Comment: huh, I didn't see that tag, and I looked.